# how to make only one list item expand when clicked- react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to make an expandable list view, so that each list item (student) will have a plus/minus button and every time it is clicked a sub list of all student's grades will expand.
With the code I have so far, when I click on one of the buttons it opens all the list items at the same time. How can I fix this so when I'm clicking on a specific student it will open only his grades? Can't seem to resolve this.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
  const [filteredStudents, setFilteredStudents] = useState([])
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)


  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setStudents(result.students);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredStudents(
      students.filter(s => {
        return s.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
          || s.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
      })
    )
  }, [search, students]);

  const toggleButton = () => {
    setOpen(!open)
  }

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="main-container">

        <ul className="list-container">
          <form >
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search by name"
              id="name-input"
              onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)}
            />
          </form>
          {filteredStudents.map(student => (
            <li className="student-container" key={student.id}>
              <img src={student.pic} alt="student"></img>
              <div className="student-info">
                <h1>{student.firstName}  {student.lastName}</h1>
                <p>Email: {student.email}</p>
                <p>Company: {student.company}</p>
                <p>Skill: {student.skill}</p>
                <p>Average: {(student.grades.reduce((a, b) => parseInt(b) + a, 0))
                  / (student.grades.map((grade) => grade).length)}%
                </p>
                {open ? (
                  <ul className="grades-list">
                    {student.grades.map((grade, index) => <li key={grade.id}>Test {index + 1}: {grade}%</li>)}
                  </ul>) : null}
              </div>

              <button className="expand-btn" onClick={() => toggleButton()}>{open ? '-' : '+'}</button>
            </li>
          ))
          }
        </ul >
      </div>
    );

  }


}

export default App;
```

it looks something like that now:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX0GU.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `open` for all items in list. You must narrow it to the currently selected student ids. So you need an array that will hold all opened ids.

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState([])

  const toggleOpen= (id) => {
    if (open.includes(id)) {
     setOpen(open.filter(sid => sid !== id))
    } else {
     let newOpen = [...open]
     newOpen.push(id)
     setOpen(newOpen)
    }
  }

  <button className="expand-btn" onClick={() => toggleOpen(student.id)}>{open.includes(student.id) ? '-' : '+'}</button>
```

and then

```
            {open.includes(student.id) ? (
              <ul className="grades-list">
                {student.grades.map((grade, index) => <li key={grade.id}>Test {index + 1}: {grade}%</li>)}
              </ul>) : null}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought it's something related to that but didn't know how to implement it. It works but now it won't close when I click on the same one I opened, only when I click on a different one. Do you know how can I fix that?

Comment: yes, correct. it needs to be an array of opened ids. check my updated answer

Comment: oh ok I get it now, it works perfectly! thanks a lot for your help!